# Null values passing on asp.net mvc 5 controller (Ninject DI)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ninject-extensions

I'm working on a MVC5 application and i'm trying to implement DI on my controller class. I have correctly put binding on Ninjectwebcommons. Still constructor of the controller class is receiving just null implementations.

```
 public class AdServiceController : Controller
{
    private IClientRequestPackage _clientReqPkg;
    private ISearchAd                 _searchAd;
    private ICreateConnection _createConnection;
    private INewConnectionResult _newConnectionResult;
    private IBuildDataObjects _buildDataObjects;
    private IAdSearchResultObj _adSearchResultObj;



    public AdServiceController (ICreateConnection createConnection)

    {
        _createConnection = createConnection;

    }
```

This createConnection implementation has a dependency on Iconfigparams. I'm seeing Iconfigparams is just null.

Any help pl.

Chanu

Comment: in unit test where I bind using kernel.Bind and gets implementations using kernel.get things works correctly.

Comment: I kind of figured out whats going on. I read config parameters from app.config. If i define values directly in the class it works. What i dont get it is in the unit test i can see values correctly passed being read from app.config.

Comment: Can you paste your DI code.